# CGContextDrawImage memory is not freed

Tags: ios, memory, cgcontext

I'm using the [PhotoScrollerNetwork project](https://github.com/dhoerl/PhotoScrollerNetwork) to provide a single high resolution image to a view in my project and automatically tile it, so memory is managed properly. It uses this block of code to draw the full high res image to memory, so that tiles can be calculated out of it.

```
-(void)drawImage:(CGImageRef)image {
       madvise(ims[0].map.addr, ims[0].map.mappedSize - ims[0].map.emptyTileRowSize, MADV_SEQUENTIAL);

       unsigned char *addr = ims[0].map.addr + ims[0].map.col0offset + ims[0].map.row0offset * ims[0].map.bytesPerRow;
       CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(addr, ims[0].map.width, ims[0].map.height, bitsPerComponent, ims[0].map.bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
       assert(context);
       CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy); // Apple uses this in QA1708
       CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, ims[0].map.width, ims[0].map.height);
       CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image);
       CGContextRelease(context);

       madvise(ims[0].map.addr, ims[0].map.mappedSize - ims[0].map.emptyTileRowSize, MADV_FREE);
 }
```

In the `dealloc` method of the class, the ims is freed ( 'free(ims)'), so this should be handled properly. However, if I make a new view (and thus a call to drawImage) repeatedly, my memory is getting filled. I found that if I comment `CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image);`, the memory is ok, so I think something is kept in memory, but I can't get what... The dealloc method is always called, so that's not the problem.

EDIT:
My image is also released properly, this is the complete flow:

```
- (void)myFunc {
        CFDictionaryRef options = [self createOptions];
        CGImageRef image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSourcRef, 0, options);
        CFRelease(options);
        CFRelease(imageSourcRef);
        if (image) {
            [self decodeImage:image];
            CGImageRelease(image);
        }
}

- (void)decodeImage:(CGImageRef)image {
    assert(decoder == cgimageDecoder);

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

#if LEVELS_INIT == 0
    zoomLevels = [self zoomLevelsForSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
    ims = calloc(zoomLevels, sizeof(imageMemory));
#endif

    [self mapMemoryForIndex:0 width:width height:height];

    [self drawImage:image];
    [self createLevelsAndTile];
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you post a question to the github support link? Its very unlikely anyone here (but me, the author of the project) can answer your question on SO :-). Probably the best thing to do is take your modified project, zip it up, and post it to a drop box account so I can take a look at it (but may not happen til this weekend).

Answer (score 0):

Running both local from-bundle images, and network images, it appears any significant leak is gone. This with iOS7 and Xcode 5.

Comment: I have 12 MB of jpg image, Every thing works perfect but CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image); cause memory to go upto 360 MB, and application crashes. Is this due to madvise? Any alternative for this function -(void)drawImage:(CGImageRef)image??

Comment: Well, try commenting that out and see. I don't know - this project ran on an original iPad which was severely memory limited.

Comment: I tried removing madvise but it seems like CGContextDrawImage internally decompresses the whole jpg thats why its taking so much memory. I am running on iPad mini with 500 MB RAM. and its crashing.